# Why every finite language is polynomial?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, computability, polynomial-time

I understand that it's possible to build TM that check all the finite number of cases, so it's definitely in $R$, but I'm not sure why it's in $P$

Comment: It’s even in linear time.

Comment: Every regular language is in linear time.

Comment: Thanks @YuvalFilmus, but you assumes that I know what's regular language and how it's related to finite language

Comment: Most theory of computation classes start with regular languages and only later proceed with Turing machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the longest word in the language has length $m$. The Turing machine reads the first $m+1$ symbols on the input tape. Based on that, it can decide whether the input belongs to the language or not. This Turing machine runs in *constant* time.

Comment: Thanks, Does It not matter the size of TM? I mean it may be ${\Sigma^*}^m$, isn't?

Comment: The size of the Turing machine is constant, like any other Turing machine.